# Release Custom Object returned by function

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a leak memory error with a custom object (called LinesOfText class) returned by a function. This is a simple example with no detailed implementation:

```
-(void)myMethod(){
LinesOfText *linesOfText = [self linesOftext:@"this is my text"];
} 

-(LinesOfText *)linesOftext:(NSString *)_string{
LinesOfText *linesOfText = [[linesOfText alloc] init];
[linesOfText propsOfTextLine:_string];
return linesOfText;
}
```

I'm not sure where I've to release the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually such methods should return an autoreleased value, that is, in your linesOftext method, do

```
return [linesOfText autorelease];
```

(or call autorelease on it right when creating it),

```
LinesOfText *linesOfText = [[[linesOfText alloc] init] autorelease];
```

By convention, if your method name contains "new", "alloc", "copy", it should return a retained object. Return an autoreleased object otherwise (e.g. see methods like NSMutableArray's arrayWithCapacity:, or NSString's stringWithFormat:...
See this for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

And yes, like zsnow suggests it may be a good idea to make it a static (+) method if possible.

Comment: For any reason your second example fails. But doing the release in the return it works! thanks

Comment: That's rather odd that it fails. Does it crash? Where? Are you sure it's not additionally released within propsOfTextLine method?

Comment: Yes, Crash and I'm sure the code is ok. I'm still looking for the problem

Answer (score 0):

In myMethod, use:

```
LinesOfText *linesOfText = [[LinesOfText linesOftext:@"this is my text"] autorelease];
```

Instead of:

```
LinesOfText *linesOfText = [self linesOftext:@"this is my text"];
```

In your other file, use:

```
+(LinesOfText *)linesOftext:(NSString *)_string {
```

Instead of:

```
-(LinesOfText *)linesOftext:(NSString *)_string {
```

Comment: It's a good idea become linesOftext:(NSString *)_string to static